# Can I install DCEVM with Oracle Java 7 HotSpot VM?

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot, hotswap, dcevm

I'm running Oracle Java 7 on MacOS (OSX 10.7.5)

java -version:

```
Java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

I recently read about [DCEVM](https://github.com/dcevm/dcevm) and am very curious to try it out.  However, I am confused about its compatibility.

According to the [binaries download page](https://dcevm.github.io/), there are binaries for OpenJDK Java 7 update 51, build 3.  I'm not quite sure how that relates to the Java version I currently have on my machine.

Does the install JRE need to match the DCEVM Hotspot version?  Do I need to install OpenJDK 7_51_3 to be able to use the DCEVM in question?  Or can I install the hotspot VM with my Oracle JRE?

I'm not entirely sure exactly how all the utilities that come with a JRE/JDK interact with the HotSpot VM and if they all have to be of the same build or not, given that compiled byte code should be able to run on any JVM of the same major build number.

Can anyone provide a little insight how all these components fit together?

As a followup, does anyone know if/how/where I can find a compatible version of OpenJDK for OSX on which I can run [DCEVM for Java 7 update 51, build 3?](https://github.com/dcevm/dcevm/releases/download/full-7u51%2B3/installer-full-jdk7u51.3.jar)?

Comment: The short answer is no. The project modifies the hotspot compiler in the JVM, it is not byte code (it is native code). You can find more on the [original](http://ssw.jku.at/dcevm/) project page.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I realize that it is not bytecode.  What I meant by that comment, is that all HotSpots should be able to offer the same functionality.  But where I am unsure is if the HotSpot VM is a static-built file, or if is dependent on several different libs/etc.  If the former, then I assume that multiple HotSpots can co-exist within a single Java install, but if they are all dynamically linked, then I presume I need the same OpenJDK version.  Does that also imply the exact same build as well?

Comment: I believe so, there are admonitions to use a supported version. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - I didn't try it.  I was afraid to screw up my Java install on my Mac.  And unlike Windows or Linux where I find installing Java is simple, any time I try to change/update Java on my Mac causes me grief (non-standard directory naming, etc).  So trying to get info before I blow something up. :)

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't have any problem to use DCEVM inside OracleVM. DCEVM is now maintained by [this project](https://github.com/dcevm/dcevm). You can find the [answer to your question here](https://github.com/dcevm/dcevm/issues/49).